Does the question "will I get transplanted" make sense to your ears?
I work as a medical interpreter and the other day one of the patients said something that word for word would be structured in Spanish like "Will I get transplanted" I was not sure how to translate it to English so I put it like "Will I get the transplant" which was the best rendition that sprang to my mind, the verb get embodies a very complex and varied semantics so that saying "will I get transplanted" could imply "will my location be switched" but saying "will I get the transplantation" conveys the meaning of actually getting something implanted inside of her, Do you believe the translation was accurate?

If I worked as a medical interpreter, I'd understand "Will I get the transplant?" If I worked in immigration, I'd understand "Will I be relocated?" In English, I will not get transplanted, the organ will be.

If the patient is in a terminal condition, are they concerned about the future of their own organs?

The literal translation into Spanish would also be wrong. People use all kinds of funny language. What exactly was the Spanish? I am an interpreter, too. Did they mean "trasladado"?? Your question is not clear. Give me the actual Spanish used.

Entonces doctor, ¿Seré transplantada?

Your substitution of "get the transplant" seems appropriate, since we translate overall meaning rather than one word at a time. I'm not familiar with the Spanish usage, but in English, the object of "transplant" is the actual object that's being moved to a new location, like an organ or plant, so for a person to "get transplanted" usually means to be relocated.
And although "transplantation" is a word for the general concept, you were also right to choose "transplant." Note that the Wikipedia article on "Organ transplantation" also uses "transplant" as a noun throughout to refer to individual procedures.

To 'transplant' means to move from one place to another. In an organ transplant procedure, the organ is getting transplanted, not the patient.
So it would be wrong to say "I am getting transplanted" to mean you were receiving an organ transplant operation. Although the word 'transplant' is more often than not used in a medical context, you might occasionally hear someone has been 'transplanted' to a new home or workplace.
I can understand the error - it is not uncommon for English nouns to become verbs that describe the effect on someone or something (eg "I Googled him") but in this case, the noun 'transplant' (an operation involving organ transplantation) is derived from the verb to transplant (the organ) so it doesn't work using it as a verb on the patient.
The most common usage is with 'transplant' as a countable noun, so you'd be right in saying "receive the transplant" or "get the transplant".

I would not go so far as saying that it is "wrong". Having experienced the thick of things regarding a transplantation operation, I'm aware that (as in many technical fields) the language gets truncated in fast and loose ways. Even the chief surgeon might say something like "okay, let's transplant her" (referring to the patient, not the organ).

@LeeMosher and you don't think that a surgeon saying "let's transplant her" could mean something else? Like, move her to a different theatre? Because that's what transplant means - to move something from one place to another. I do appreciate that sometimes there's no need to be dogmatic and say something is "wrong", especially when it is just a question of "will I be understood?" but when there's another meaning - a correct meaning - then I think it is important to say its wrong.

Tell that to our transplant surgeon :-)

@LeeMosher I might ask one next time I speak to one, as I'm a senior health data analyst specialising in acute scheduled care which includes theatre data. All I can say is that in 25 years I've never heard the term, but I appreciate that terminology differs from place to place and maybe surgeons in your country say "lets transplant her" all the time. But even then, we are here to learn English, not workplace terminology.

"transplant" (noun) can refer to the donated organ.

Will I get the transplant?

That would be a likely question from someone who has been on a "transplant  waiting list" or is seeking to be placed on one, and has just undergone an examination and evaluation or re-evaluation.
P.S. If Spanish speakers are similar to English speakers, some will use the passive form to refer to them undergoing a medical procedure:

Will I get bypassed?

That is, will I have a coronary artery bypass procedure performed on me?
Here's an actual sentence with a medical practitioner doing the talking:

... I think it’s worth noting that ... these patients were really sick. They had multi-vessel coronary disease that’s amenable to bypass. 40% had diabetes, they had low EFs, and most of them had symptoms of both heart failure and angina. I think it’s pretty telling just how sick they were, that when you look at the long-term follow-up data for these patients, for the ones who didn’t get bypassed, two-thirds of them had died.
[my emphasis]


In the UK if somebody said "Will I get bypassed", I would assume they are asking if the local authority is going to build a road to bypass their town. LOL.

Considering the context of the dialog, if you had translated the sentence as "will I get transplanted", it's very likely that a physician who was fluent in English would understand.
If someone were discussing changing someone's location, we do use transplant in some contexts, e.g. "I'm a transplant from Minnesota". In the hospital setting, fluent English speakers would say relocated or transferred to another room. It is very unlikely that a fluent English speaker would have interpreted "will I be transplanted?" as being about a transfer to a different room or setting.
Speaking of setting, if this was an inpatient setting, meaning that the patient is admitted to the hospital for an overnight stay, it's possible that they would discharge the patient and have them readmitted for surgery at a later date, or discharge them and treat them as an outpatient. If in the hospital setting, outpatient means they don't stay overnight and are under less intensive observation; outpatient surgery is common, but despite lacking medical knowledge, it seems safe to say that you wouldn't get organ transplantation on an outpatient basis. There is a whole lot of technical vocabulary around the distinction between being in the ER, being actually admitted, or being in observation status (without technically being admitted as an inpatient, done for financial reasons), which you might unfortunately encounter at some point. It would mostly matter for insurance coverage purposes.

Will I get a/the transplant?
Means will I get the relevant organ surgically implanted in me? “A” meaning any organ, “the” meaning this specific organ.
Will I be transported/transferred?
Means will I be moved?
Transported would be used where we were focusing on the transportation - you can be transported anywhere.
Transferred would be used where you were focusing on the destination, specifically where the destination is of the same type as the origin. So you can be transferred from one hospital to another hospital or one school to another school, but you can’t be transferred from a hospital to a school.
